# Specific rounded navigation

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to make properly such navigation bar, especially this two intersecting lines. I know that I can use `transform: skewX(10deg);` for rotating this vertical line, but not sure am I ok with whole html&css

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<main>
   <div class="rounded-rectangle">
      <ul class="top">
         <li>
            <button>text</button>
         </li>
         <li>
            <button>text</button>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="bottom">
         <li>
            <button>text</button>
         </li>
         <li>
            <button>text</button>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</main>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0jgcny6/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could use pseudo elements of the container to draw the intersecting lines.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color: #e24d3d;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

ul li {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

button:focus {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0px;
}

ul.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 50%;
}

ul.top div:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}

ul.bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 50%;
}

.rounded-rectangle {
  background-color: rgba(128, 213, 226, 0.4);
  height: 320px;
  max-width: 520px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.rounded-rectangle:before, .rounded-rectangle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}

.rounded-rectangle:before {
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}

.rounded-rectangle:after {
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="rounded-rectangle">
    <ul class="top">
      <li>
        <button>text</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button>text</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="bottom">
      <li>
        <button>text</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button>text</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I have minor problem. When I'm decreasing height for example min-height: 110px, text inside isn't responsive

Comment: @cygnus sounds like that's beyond the scope of your OP, no? You should make a new post if you can't figure it out, but you need to be more specific. Change `min-height` on what? And what do you mean it isn't responsive - as in it overlaps? Sounds like you just need to use some @media queries to handle different heights and adjust the font size or something, or use `vw` or `vh` units to control the text size instead. Regardless, I think that's a little complex to solve in the comments to this post.

Comment: just figure out that i have broken height inside `li`, anyway thanks again!